# Firefox scrollTop reset on zIndex change

Tags: javascript, firefox, scrolltop

Whenever I change zIndex of given div (even to the same value) its scrollTop property resets and it scrolls back to start. This causes a very ugly effect to my site (slowdown and black rectangle over the entire div while it repaints). After scrollTop reset I can set it back, but this causes yet another ugly repaint.

This FF bug is driving me mad! I submitted a bug in mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=623937 but they don't care to work on it! Please, if somebody knows how to workaround this issue with some javascript magic? Maybe play with the HTMLElement prototype to somehow override scrollTop?

Here goes a little test case"

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#parentDiv
{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
}
div#elementToScroll
{
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 40px;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
overflow-y: hidden;
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="parentDiv">
This is the parent DIV
<div id="elementToScroll">This is the child div with overflow-y: hidden and content a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of a lot of ; </div>
</div>

<script>
var parentDIV = document.getElementById("parentDiv");
var elementToScroll = document.getElementById("elementToScroll");
alert ("elementToScroll.scrollTop initial: " + elementToScroll.scrollTop);
elementToScroll.scrollTop = 20;
alert ("We set elementToScroll.scrollTop = 20: current value is: " + elementToScroll.scrollTop);
parentDIV.style.zIndex = 0;
alert ("We set parentDIV.style.zIndex and now elementToScroll.scrollTop is: " + elementToScroll.scrollTop);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's a complete mystery how Firefox decides what bugs submitted by real developers are to be fixed.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be specific to zIndex. Toggling the visibility style also appears to reset the scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and nothing is wrong with Firefox 4:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The bug exists with FF 3.6 But I am glad it is gone with 4.0 Looking forward to see it final.